# What is the difference to compute double integral?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I see a double integral on web with a strange way to calculate. Please help me to make it clear.
Here is the integral:

$$\int_1^2\int_1^2(x+y)\ dx\ dy$$

As my way, I calculate it:

$$\int_1^2\int_1^2(x+y)\ dx\ dy= \int_1^2\left. {\left( {\frac{{{x^2}}}{2} + xy} \right)} \right|_{x = 1}^{x = 2}dy =\int_1^2 (\frac{3}{2}+y)\ dy $$.

But in the solution, they work is very strange:

\begin{array}{l}
\int\limits_1^2 {\int\limits_1^2 {\left( {x + y} \right)dxdy = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_1^2 {\left. {{{\left( {x + y} \right)}^2}} \right|_{x = 1}^{x = 2}dy} } } \\
   = \frac{1}{2}\int\limits_1^2 {\left[ {{{\left( {y + 2} \right)}^2} - {{\left( {y + 1} \right)}^2}} \right]dy} \\
 = \frac{1}{6}\left[ {{{\left( {y + 2} \right)}^3} - {{\left( {y + 1} \right)}^3}} \right]_{y = 1}^{y = 2}
\end{array}.

Two way out two results, but their result is right.

Pls help me explain?

Comment: the equivalent of u-substitution for integrals over multiple variables.  u=x+y and v=y  the jacobian is 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one approach is using substitution $u=x+y\;\Rightarrow\;du=dx$, then the inner integral turns out to be
$$
\int_{1}^2 (x+y)\ dx = \int_{x=1}^2 u\ du = \left.\frac12u^2\right|_{x=1}^2 = \left.\frac12(x+y)^2\right|_{x=1}^2=\frac12\left[(y+2)^2-(y+1)^2\right].
$$
Similarly, the next integral is solved by using substitution $u=y+2\;\Rightarrow\;du=dy$ and $v=y+1\;\Rightarrow\;dv=dy$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question since the two ways give the same result.
One consider the primitive $x\mapsto \frac{x^2}{2}+xy$ for $x\mapsto x+y$ and the other $x\mapsto (x+y)^2$ but the result is the same.

To make it clearer, try to calculate$$\frac{(y+2)^2-(y+1)^2}{2}$$ and compare it to $$\frac{3}{2}+y$$

Comment: They already know that the result is correct, this is explicitly stated in the question. They want to understand the method used. This answer doesn't seem very helpful.

Comment: The OP said the two integrals DON'T give the same result. I've tried to show him it's wrong.